# Toilet Water Shoots upwards When Flushed like a volcano erupting

Tags: toilet

This issue is with an American Standard single piece toilet. I just changed the 'fill valve' and since then the toilet water erupts shoot upwards, making a mess. The amount of water shooting upwards is very little but enough to reach the toilet seat. The Toilet does not seem to be plugged. I talked to the plumber about this, and he suggested using the 'SNAKE' to clear any blockages.

Comment: Have you tried the plumbers suggestion? Seems pretty valid.

Comment: Has anyone taken into consideration day in the application of a mobile home possibility of a bad studor vent or several old abs type aav’s you find in a mobile home

Answer (score 7):

Water probably isn't "shooting upwards", but rather not draining fast enough based on the inflow of water.  Per your plumber, it is probably partially clogged.  With a toilet, you want to use a toilet auger instead of a snake as it is designed to get around the bend without damaging the finish of your toilet.

If you want to confirm its a draining issue, try pouring a bucket of water into the toilet. It should drain almost instantly without the level increasing.  If it doesn't, it's clogged.

Answer (score 2):

If the proper amount of water is not delivered to the toilet, it can splash. I experienced splashing of water with an Eljer toilet when the rubber fill hose was not properly clipped into the (vertical) overflow tube. Also, make sure that the new valve is adjusted to close at the proper tank water level.

Another possibility is that the drain is blocked. If this is the case, the drain needs to be cleared. There are special toilet augers designed not to scratch your toilet's finish, though sometimes it may be easier to remove the toilet, clean the drain, replace the wax gasket, and reinstall the toilet.

Comment: I am inclined to go with your suggestion about the 'rubber fill hose' not being properly clipped. As this replacement was a precursor to the problem. Thanks

Comment: Great. If this solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you could mark this answer as correct. Otherwise, let us know how your debugging progresses. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually as a similar problem kept worsening I noticed that the water flow from the holes under the rim of the bowl was not even all around the rim and maybe nothing in the arc maybe 4 to 6 if considering it as the face of a clock.  Sometimes little black blobs came from some of the water holes.  Perhaps some organic matter had back-flowed into the rim and there was mold or fungus growing in the rim.

I used a leftover printer re-inking kit syringe with a blunt metal “needle” about 2” long to inject a bleach and detergent solution into the holes around the circumference of the bowl rim and that helped.  I repeated that about a month later and no more geyser.

I first cleaned the bowl with a disinfectant cleaner and rinsed out the cleaner and then poured water into the bowl to syphon much of the water out.  The solution was about 4 ounces of 4.5% liquid bleach in a quart of water and maybe a teaspoon of dish detergent.  I used ventilation of the room, gloves and eye protection while working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of water splashing out of the toilet bowl when it was flushed. This began to happen after I replaced the fill valve. Based on the information here I checked the placement of the refill tube coming off the fill valve. The refill tube had come loose from the overflow tube and just hung down into the water of the tank. I reconnected it to the top of the overflow tube (in my case there is an obvious place for it on the rim of the overflow tube although sometimes there is a plastic clip to hold the refill tube in place over the overflow tube) and the water in the bowl once more flows smoothly without splashing. Thanks for the question and responses.

Answer (score 0):

Had the geyser problem.

1. Emptied a bucket of water into the bowl. Immediately drained so that meant no blockage.
2. Used a thin drill bit to clear the holes under the bowl rim that are slanted to cause circulating water down the sides of the bowl.
   Problem fixed.